# Change color of specific circle in the packed circle chart (amcharts)

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

How can we change the color used in amcharts for packed circle chart? we can set the theme but what I'm trying to do is to override the color for specific circles I can define in the JSON. any idea how can we do this?

They use example here https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/mgEXeq , Let's say I want to change the color of the circle with title "Fourth" to green. I added color attribute but it didn't work

```
{
        name: "Fourth",
        color: "green",
        children: [
          { name: "D1", value: 415 },
          { name: "D2", value: 148 },
          { name: "D3", value: 89 }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [property field](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Property_fields) to map the `stroke` and `fill` properties to your data's `color` field. In a force directed node chart, you need to define these properties on the node's `circle` and `outerCircle` objects:

```
series.nodes.template.outerCircle.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
series.nodes.template.circle.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
series.nodes.template.circle.propertyFields.fill = "color";
```

Note that your sample will only set the parent node to green. You will need to set the color on each child node if you also want them set to green.

Demo below:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);
var series = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries())

chart.data = [
  {
    name: "Core",
    children: [
      {
        name: "First",
        children: [
          { name: "A1", value: 100 },
          { name: "A2", value: 60 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Second",
        children: [
          { name: "B1", value: 135 },
          { name: "B2", value: 98 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Third",
        children: [
          {
            name: "C1",
            children: [
              { name: "EE1", value: 130 },
              { name: "EE2", value: 87 },
              { name: "EE3", value: 55 }
            ]
          },
          { name: "C2", value: 148 },
          {
            name: "C3", children: [
              { name: "CC1", value: 53 },
              { name: "CC2", value: 30 }
            ]
          },
          { name: "C4", value: 26 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Fourth",
        color: "green",
        children: [
          { name: "D1", value: 415 },
          { name: "D2", value: 148 },
          { name: "D3", value: 89 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Fifth",
        children: [
          {
            name: "E1",
            children: [
              { name: "EE1", value: 33 },
              { name: "EE2", value: 40 },
              { name: "EE3", value: 89 }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "E2",
            value: 148
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
  }
];

series.dataFields.value = "value";
series.dataFields.name = "name";
series.dataFields.children = "children";
series.nodes.template.tooltipText = "{name}:{value}";
series.nodes.template.fillOpacity = 1;
series.nodes.template.outerCircle.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
series.nodes.template.circle.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
series.nodes.template.circle.propertyFields.fill = "color";

series.nodes.template.label.text = "{name}"
series.fontSize = 10;
series.minRadius = 15;
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/forceDirected.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```